# Search (in Oracle), using wild card without worrying about the case or order in which the words appear

Tags: sql, oracle, wildcard

How to search using wild card (in Oracle), without worrying about case or order in which the words appear.

e.g. if I search for `like '%a%b%'`, it should return values containing    *a*b*, *A*B* ,*b*a* and *B*A*  This is just a sample, the search may have 5 or more words, is it possible get the result in just one expression rather than using AND.

Comment: What is the problem with using AND?

Comment: SQL is not really designed to do that kind of searching ... you'll want to investigate a full-text solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the issue with using AND is that, as the number of search terms increases, so does the number of possible combinations. With two search terms there are only two combinations, with three there are six, with four 10, with five 15, etc.

Comment: Look ad @podiluska's solution.  You don't have to do any combinatorics.  You are just looking for each value independently and combining the results together.  I think it is an elegant solution.

Comment: @DavidFaber With two there are 2, with 3 there are 3, with 4 there are 4, surely?

Comment: Three search terms A, B, and C - combinations (1) %A%B%C, (2) %A%C%B%, (3) %B%A%C%, (4) %B%C%A%, (5) %C%A%B%, (6) %C%B%A%

Comment: Ack, I see now ... I thinking `OR` instead of `AND`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from yourtable
where yourfield like '%a%'
and yourfield like '%b%'
```

Or you can investigate [Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm)

Comment: It looks like Oracle Text is what you're after - specifically, the contains query

Comment: I would also like to ignore the case of the terms, just like google

Comment: Just use "lower(yourfield)" instead of "yourfield" in both places

Comment: See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_case_insensitive_indexes_searches.htm for case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
 where upper(column) like '%A%B%';
```

or

```
select * from table
 where lower(column) like '%a%b%';
```

or

```
select * from table
 where upper(column) like '%A%'
   and upper(column) like '%B%';
```

or

```
select * from table
 where lower(column) like '%a%'
   and lower(column) like '%b%';
```

However, if you would like to find out `*a*b*` or `*b*a*` and so on. The other solution would be to sort the `CHARS` in the `VARCHAR` first i.e. if you have a string like `aebcd` then sort it to `abcde` and then do pattern match using like. As per [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1791550) you can use below query to sort the chars in a varchar and then do the pattern match on it.

```
SELECT 1 val
FROM (SELECT MIN(permutations) col
        FROM (SELECT REPLACE (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (n, ','), ',') permutations
                FROM (SELECT LEVEL l, SUBSTR ('cba', LEVEL, 1) n
                        FROM DUAL   --replace dual by your table
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH ('cba')) yourtable
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE l != PRIOR l)
        WHERE LENGTH (permutations) = LENGTH ('cba')) temp_tab
  WHERE upper(col) like '%A%B%';
```

Returns

```
val 
------------------
1
```